# Set sum in css property

Tags: css

I have several divs with a determined css class.

I want to manually add pixels to top property:

> .class {    top: 100px; }
>
> div class="class" style="top:+=50px"

Is it possible do to something like that?

Comment: What is the use case behind this? What does manually mean? If you hard-code it, you might as well do it in the CSS file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not with straight CSS. Using a preprocessor like [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) or [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) can do that server-side.

You can accomplish the same thing with jQuery/JavaScript.

```
var class = $('.class');
var top = class.css('top').substr(0,class.css('top').length - 2);
top += //your value here
class.css('top',top + 'px');
```

Answer (score 2):

No, not reliably anyway.

There is a CSS3 property called calc() which would do it but it isn't going to work anywhere but the latest browsers and support may be flakey.

More on it here.
http://robertnyman.com/css3/calc/calc.html

Depending on the reasons you want to do this you might want to look into using a CSS Pre-Processor such as LESS or SASS.

What is the reason you want to do this? There may be a solution that isn't immediately obvious from the question posed.

Answer (score 2):

CSS3 transforms might be useful here.  Like:

```
.class { top: 100px; }

div class="class" style="transform:translate(0,50px)"
```

You'd have to add all the vendor prefixes, though, like:

```
style="transform:translate(0,50px);-webkit-transform:translate(0,50px);-o-transform:translate(0,50px);-ms-transform:translate(0,50px);-moz-transform:translate(0,50px)"
```

Answer (score 1):

No, not with just CSS.

You could do it with some server-side code or with JavaScript in the browser.

Another approach could be to use something like [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) or [SAAS](http://sass-lang.com/) which support variables and simple calculations.

Answer (score 0):

It's now possible with CSS [variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties) and [`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) function.

```css
.class {
  --top-add: 0px; /* Default value overridden in inline styles */
  top: calc(100px + var(--top-add));
}
```

```html
<div class="class" style="--top-add: 50px">...</div>
```